# Self JOIN query using EF-Core

Tags: c#, sql, ef-core-3.1

I have an old stored procedure selecting data from a self-referencing table.

```
exists (select * 
        from MyTable t1
        join MyTable t2 on t1.model = t2.model
        where t1.name = 'Name1'
          and t1.value = 'Value1'
          and t2.name = 'Name2'
          and t2.value = 'Value2'
          and t1.model = @model)
```

We move the code to EF Core. Is there a more efficient way of building the above query?

I can imagine something like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM MyTable 
WHERE 
    (model= @model) AND (
    (name = 'Name1' AND value = 'Value1') OR
    (name = 'Name2' AND value = 'Value2'))
```

and checking the returned value, so in EF

```
var v = await repository
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(t => t.model == model && 
               (t.name == 'Name1' && t.value='Value1' || 
                t.name == 'Name2' && t.value == 'Value2'))
    .CountAsync();
```

Is this a more efficient approach comparing to the JOIN? I can see there is a difference, however, the result should be the same based on the nature of our data.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

Which is faster depends on *your* data, *your* data model and the system *you* are running it on.  For this reason, you should test the two versions on your system.

In general, though, the `exists` can stop at the first row that it encounters that matches the conditions.  Assuming that you have appropriate indexes, then the overhead of the `join` should be minimal.  Because it can stop quicker, it is reasonable to assume that that version would be faster than an approach that uses aggregation.  Aggregation requires finding *all* matches, so even if there is only one, it needs to keep looking for all of them to return a count of 1.